# HAProxy to route applications runnig on different ports

Tags: haproxy

Hi I'm trying to configure HAProxy but I'm having some troubles. We have a single server running two applications (odoomexy,odoopepess) one of them running throught port 8069 and the other throught port 8070. Right now we access these applications using ipserver:8069 and ipserver:8070 however we faced slow response and many connection errors. This is haproxy.cfg:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    log     global
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect  5000
    timeout client  10000
    timeout server  10000
    listen appname 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    stats enable
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats realm Strictly\ Private
    stats auth A_Username:odoo
    stats auth Another_User:foo
    balance roundrobin
    option httpclose
    option forwardfor
backend odoo_mexy
    server odoomexy 127.0.0.1:8069  check
backend odoo_pepess
    server odoopepess 127.0.0.1:8070  check
frontend odoo_IN
    bind 127.0.0.1:8090
    bind 127.0.0.1:8091
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option tcpka
    timeout client 60m
    timeout server 60m
    timeout http-keep-alive 1m
    acl d1 dst_port 8090
    use_backend odoo_mexy if d1
    acl d2 dst_port 8091
    use_backend odoo_pepess if d2
```

And I got this error log:

```
 * Starting haproxy
[WARNING] 356/120356 (18401) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : server timeout will be ignored because frontend 'odoo_IN' has no backend capability
[WARNING] 356/120356 (18402) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : server timeout will be ignored because frontend 'odoo_IN' has no backend capability
[ALERT] 356/120356 (18402) : Starting proxy appname: cannot bind socket
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you starting HAProxy as root?  Can't bind to port 80 otherwise.

Comment: Yes, starting as root and thorws the error.

Comment: Is something already listening in port 80?  That is what it sounds like may be the case, then.